# django-waffle does not show proper flag status on waffle_status endpoint

Tags: django

I have created this flag:

[image: waffle admin config]

I'm trying to get the flag status using the `waffle_status` endpoint, but no matter if the user is logged or not I get the same response:

```json
{
    "flags": {
        "test_flag": {
            "is_active": false,
            "last_modified": "2023-12-21T16:03:38.922Z"
        }
    },
    "switches": {},
    "samples": {}
}
```

It is supposed that I have to get this flag as True for the user farid, the one with id 1, isn't?

I made this exercise using django 4, django-waffle 4.1.0, and I have made this configs on settings.py

```py
.
.
.
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'waffle',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'exammple'
]
.
.
.

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'waffle.middleware.WaffleMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
.
.
.
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ]
}
.
.
.
```

and in project's url.py file

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/v1/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path(
        'api/v1/', include(
            [
                path('', include(example_urls))
            ]
        )
    ),
    path('waffle/', include('waffle.urls')),
]
```

Is this a bug/missing feature on waffle? or I'm missing some config in somewhere?

P.S. The purpose of this is that I have to give this flag status to a FrontEnd app to show or hide some visual components depending on the flag's status.

I've tried mixing configs on django admin, and settings.py, and the expected result is that the `waffle_status` endpoint returns `True` if the user who made the request is in the added ones on the flag config, otherwise has to return `False`

**UPDATE1**: I did clone the repo of the django-waffle project and I wrote this test:

```py
 def test_waffle_json_user_flag(self):
        user = get_user_model().objects.create(username='someone_else')
        flag = waffle.get_waffle_flag_model().objects.create(name='myflag')
        flag.users.add(user)
        self.client.force_login(user=user)
        response = self.client.get(reverse('waffle_status'))
        content = response.json()
        self.assertTrue(content['flags']['myflag']['is_active'])

        another_user = get_user_model().objects.create(username='another_one')
        self.client.force_login(user=another_user)
        another_response = self.client.get(reverse('waffle_status'))
        another_content = another_response.json()
        self.assertFalse(another_content['flags']['myflag']['is_active'])
```

It passed successfully!

Then I ran the django server on the project, I did create a flag and bind a user to it. I did tests using postman and I get the same issue as described above.

Doing some debug on the `waffle_status` view on waffle-django package, I saw that the request delivered came without user, I meant if I dig into `request.user` i saw `AnonymousUser` so, what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: you're missing the `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`, I don't know your implementation of token handling but let's say someone is using session authentication then the following would work:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
    ],
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated",
    ],
    ...

}
```

**Longer answer:**

You're almost there! Generally speaking there are two aspects to take into account when handling users:

- Authentication: verify if the user is who the user claims to be, so you can log the user in safely and give him a token/session
- Authorization: specifying access/rights that the user has

At the moment you're only checking for the Authorization part with `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES`, but you're not defining any authorization classes so DRF won't check who the user is (and therefore the user will always be a `AnonymousUser`.). This can be useful in some cases, e.g. a public endpoints generally doesn't need user data, hence validating it's session / decoding jwt is just overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this myself. This is because DRF doesn't perform authentication in the middleware. From the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#:%7E:text=Authentication%20always%20runs%20at%20the,contrib.auth%20package%27s%20User%20class):

> Authentication always runs at the very start of the view, before the permission and throttling checks occur, and before any other code is allowed to proceed.

To solve this, you need to wrap the `waffle_json` call in a view (or you could do this in middleware if you prefer) that optionally authenticates the user, and then call the `waffle_json` view with the modified request.

Example:

```py
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.exceptions import AuthenticationFailed
from knox.auth import TokenAuthentication
from waffle.views import waffle_json



class WaffleFeatureFlagsView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Returns the list of feature flags and their values."""

        token = request.META.get("HTTP_AUTHORIZATION")

        if token:
            token = token.split("Token ")[1].encode("utf-8")
            auth = TokenAuthentication()

            try:
                # I am using knox for token auth, but you can 
                # replace this part with the DRF token auth instead
                user, token = auth.authenticate_credentials(token)
            except AuthenticationFailed:
                raise PermissionDenied

            request.user = user

        return waffle_json(request)
```

Hope that helps!

Edit: Just noticed that because this happens post-middleware, waffle cookies will fail to set. The options to get around this:

1. Move this logic to a middleware itself, but that's not ideal because you will be authing the user twice (once in the middleware and again once it hits the DRF view).
2. Copy the middleware code from `WaffleMiddleware` and run it directly in the view after you get the response. You have more control over it, but will not keep up with changes when updating waffle.
3. Call the middleware directly in the view. This is a bit unconventional but it is the cleanest for code duplication:

```py
from waffle.middleware import WaffleMiddleware

...
        response = waffle_json(request)

        waffle_middleware = WaffleMiddleware(get_response=lambda request: response)
        response = waffle_middleware.process_response(request, response)

        return response
```